# Foreman and puppet notify resource in node report status

Tags: puppet, foreman

We're using Puppet + Foreman to monitor changes in environment by checking custom facts. For example, whenever a custom fact equals 'true' puppet calls the Notify resource with a message sent to the agent log. Puppet includes this message in the agent report and Foreman shows this in UI.

Problem is that whenever a message is thrown, Foreman considers this action as "Applied" and the node status changes to "Active" (blue icon). We want to keep the node at "No Changes" (Green) plus show the Notify message.

Is that possible in some way? Maybe define a new custom resource type?

Is there a way to use the Notify resource without causing puppet to report that the node has changed? Meaning just print the message to client log (and therefore the message will be visible in report) but without puppet classify the event as an applied configuration? The reason is that when puppet triggers the Notify resource, Foreman flags the node as being active (changed)

Here is the puppet code:

```
class mymodule::myclass::mysubclass {
     if $::fact023 == 'fail' {
     notify {'mynotify1':
       message => "WARNING: Node ${::fqdn} failed fact023",
       loglevel => hiera('warnings_loglevel'),
     }   } }
```

See screenshot:

[image]

UPDATE #1
I'm thinking about changing Foreman report file so that the UI will ignore Notify events so that the node's status will remain unchanged but still show the message in the report. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Is there a way to use the Notify resource without causing puppet to report that the node has changed?
Meaning just print the message to client log (and therefore the message will be visible in report)  but without puppet classify the event as an applied configuration?

The reason is that when puppet triggers the Notify resource, Foreman flags the node as being active (changed)

Comment: probably forgot to copy screenshot?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vmxya.png

Comment: please, add the image and the additional comment into edited question in some reasonable manner to make it readable.

Comment: Edited as per your request

Comment: I've found this to be my exact situation:
http://projects.theforeman.org/issues/1443

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Sorry, mixed up my answer with warnings issues by types and provides. Apparently thats a part of the warning business I missed...